# For iOS can you force SMS over MMS programmatically

Tags: ios, sms, mms

I have a iOS app that is using the standard `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send a text with URL in it to people.  Looking at the iPhone settings you can turn on MMS.  Is there a way to force sending SMS even if the phone settings have MMS turned on when launching `MFMessageComposeViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to force anything unfortunately. You just get a message compose view that does what it does. Although, it should use SMS by default unless you add media.